# Migration of data from CiviCRM Drupal 7 to CiviCRM in WordPress (Version 4.9.4)

Tags: wordpress, drupal, webform-civicrm, migration, compatiblity

We are currently setting up a new website for a client. They old site is using CiviCRM Drupal 7. However the fields in the new site using CiviCRM in  WordPress (Version 4.9.4) the fields of the database do not match. Is there a way to solve this backward compatability problem?

It is not allowing us to migrate the historical data to the new WordPress site by importing the data. Has any one an idea how we can resolve this, with out losing the historical data?

Comment: You say "However the fields in the new site using CiviCRM in WordPress (Version 4.9.4) the fields of the database do not match". Can you be more specific with some examples

Answer (score 1):

You can migrate the CiviCRM data between different CMS platforms but there are several steps to go through.  See [Switching CMS platforms](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-cms/) and [Moving an Existing Installation to a New Server or Location](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/) to understand the issues involved.

Make sure you use the same version of CiviCRM on the Drupal and WordPress sites.  You can upgrade later.

Moving other Drupal content to WordPress is a different issue.